# When I should close the session, acquired from HibernateSessionManager in Tapestry?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, tapestry

When I should close the session, acquired from `HibernateSessionManager` in Tapestry?

Some piece of code. Consider some method, which deals with `HibernateSessionManager` object:

```
public void foo(final HibernateSessionManager hsm) {
    Session session = hsm.getSession();
```

---

First case: session is used only for fetching data from DB:

```
session.createQuery("from SomeTable ... blablabla").list();
```

Must I close `session` (`session.close();`) manually?

---

Second case: session is used also for saving/updating results:

```
session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
```

Is it enough to just `commit` on `hsm` object: `hsm.commit();`, or I should also do `session.close();`?

Answer (score 1):

I have already answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550464/tapestry-services-implemetation-with-hibernate-usage/15551083#15551083).

To answer the other part, you don't have to worry about closing the session as it is by tapestry-hibernate for you as long as you use `HibernateSessionManager`.

```
try {
   do_stuff(hibernateSessionManager.getSession());
   hibernateSessionManager.commit();
}catch(Exception ex){
   hibernateSessionManager.abort();
}
```

Comment: Neither. I've also commented your answer in your previous post.

Comment: Furthermore, you are not answering the question. What about my first case? Should I commit after just fetching the results?

Comment: All transactions not committed are rolled back before closing the session by tapestry

Comment: Why do you think, that Tapestry will close my session automatically, if I'm working with it in separate service?

Comment: `HibernateSessionManagerImpl` implements `ThreadCleanupListener` and closes the session as part of the [cleanup](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/tapestry5/internal/hibernate/HibernateSessionManagerImpl.html#line.63).

Comment: And what? This will close session when thread will die. What it will do, if it deals with service, which will never die until application will not be terminated?

Comment: HibernateSessionManager is a per-thread service and it is removed/cleaned up after each request. So your service will keep getting the sessions but those sessions will be cleared after each request so you don't have to close them.