# Tapestry services implemetation with Hibernate usage

Tags: java, hibernate, tapestry

I'm talking about T5, Java 1.7.

I can not find any enough detailed tutorial about using hibernate inside Tapestry services.
What I need is to create Tapestry service which could deal with hibernate independently. This could be scheduler service, for example.
This service will deal with some objects and their state in DB, and work in background of application.

The question is, how correctly bind it with Hibernate? Which object of Hibernate should be injected for further work inside this Service?

---

The current approach is to inject inside this service a `HibernateSessionSource` object (passing its instance through constructor of service), and then manually create sessions, begin the transactions and so on. E.g.:

```
public synchronized void deleteJob(long id) {
    Session session = hss.create();
    JobItem job = (JobItem) session.get(JobItem.class, id);
    if (job != null) {
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            session.delete(job);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            tx.rollback();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

It looks very ugly, not in style of Tapestry. What it is the smart approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question consists of 2 parts:

**How to use hibernate inside tapestry managed services?**

You can inject hibernate session in your service using `@Inject` annotation:

```
@Inject
private Session session;
```

or as a constructor parameter:

```
public MyService buildMyService(Session session) {
  return new MyAwsomeService(session);
}
```

Then you can use it inside service. This session is managed by tapestry as a perthread service. It will be opened on first usage and be closed after end of request.

**How to use hiberanate transations inside tapestry managed services?**

You can do this manually using injected [HibernateSessionManager](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/hibernate/HibernateSessionManager.html):

```
@Inject
private HibernateSessionManager manager;

public void doSomeWork(Entity entity) {
  try {
    session.delete(entity);
    manager.commit();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    manager.abort();
  }
}
```

Or you can annotate all transactional methods with `@CommitAfter` and [advise services](http://tapestry.apache.org/service-advisors.html) using [HibernateTransactionAdvisor](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/hibernate/HibernateTransactionAdvisor.html):

```
public interface MyService {

  @CommitAfter
  void doSomeWork(Entity entity);

}

public class MyTapestryModule {
  @Match("*Service")
  public void adviseTransactions(HibernateTransactionAdvisor advisor,
                                 MethodAdviceReceiver receiver) {
    advisor.addTransactionCommitAdvice(receiver);
  }
}
```

Or you can [decorate sevices](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry-ioc-decorators.html) using [HibernateTransactionDecorator](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/hibernate/HibernateTransactionDecorator.html):

```
public class MyTapestryModule {
  @Match("*Service")
  public <T> T decorateTransactions(Class<T> serviceInterface,
                                    T delegate,
                                    String serviceId,
                                    HibernateTransactionDecorator decorator) {
    return decorator.build(serviceInterface, delegate, serviceId);
  }
}
```

How it works. It will start new transaction before method invocation and try to commit after. If any error occurs during method invocation this transaction will be rolled back.

Comment: Well, first thank you for detailed answer. I should check all these opportunities: will it work or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HibernateSessionManager](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/hibernate/HibernateSessionManager.html) if you are dealing with non-tapestry managed services.

```
try {
   do_stuff(hibernateSessionManager.getSession());
   hibernateSessionManager.commit();
}catch(Exception ex){
   hibernateSessionManager.abort();
}
```

For tapestry managed services and pages/components you can read the detailed documentation. Here are a few links

1. http://tapestry.apache.org/using-tapestry-with-hibernate.html
2. http://tapestry.apache.org/hibernate-user-guide.html

Comment: Unfortunately this approach leads to connections leaks. It was detected after migration to `The Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool` (http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html)

Comment: This is the right approach as far as I know. If there is a leak, you should report it.

Comment: Oops! I looked at deleteJob and thought you are trying to use it in a job which is instantiated outside tapestry. Now looking at the question again, I think you have not properly gone through the documentation. I am adding some links to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can @Inject the Session directly instead of the HibernateSessionManager.

The Session tapestry provides is actually a per thread, lazy loading proxy. The underlying session is managed by tapestry and is cleaned up by the PerThreadManager after each request.

It's almost magic!

Comment: You can either annotate a tapestry managed service with @CommitAfter or you can call HibernateSessionManager.commit()